# ROR - Loop through active record result and form an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to form an array from the result I got from querying the database

```
industries = Industry.find_by_name(j['Categories']).industries
```

The result that i get is as following

```
[#<Industry id: 3717, staffroom_type: "Industry", name: "Home Service", created_at: "2016-01-19 02:33:30", updated_at: "2016-01-19 05:25:53", parent_id: nil, user_cannot_join_shortlists: false, location: "SYDNEY, NSW, 2000", latitude: -33.8674769, longitude: 151.2069776, shortlist_introduction_email_subject: nil, shortlist_introduction_email_body: nil, external_job_url_enabled: false, deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, account_id: 3506, create_group_permission: false, create_role_permission: false, edit_group_permission: true, uuid: "70ef9351-f517-40a9-a300-8c1078da033a", staffroom_image_file_name: nil, staffroom_image_content_type: nil, staffroom_image_file_size: nil, staffroom_image_updated_at: nil, staffroom_image_repository: "production", cached_staffroom_image_id: nil, industry_type_id: nil, company_id: nil, billed_to: "employer", admin_user_id: nil, send_job_notifications: true, do_not_feature_jobs: false, company_type: nil, company_type_other: nil, company_restriction: nil, shortlist_count: nil>,
 #<Industry id: 1624, staffroom_type: "Industry", name: "Aged and Disability Care", created_at: "2015-04-13 02:07:53", updated_at: "2017-05-30 10:49:17", parent_id: nil, user_cannot_join_shortlists: false, location: "NOT PROVIDED (Assuming Sydney, 2000)", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, shortlist_introduction_email_subject: nil, shortlist_introduction_email_body: nil, external_job_url_enabled: false, deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, account_id: 3506, create_group_permission: false, create_role_permission: false, edit_group_permission: true, uuid: "f4b7bac3-3587-4056-a88f-9a9e98c42197", staffroom_image_file_name: nil, staffroom_image_content_type: nil, staffroom_image_file_size: nil, staffroom_image_updated_at: nil, staffroom_image_repository: "production", cached_staffroom_image_id: nil, industry_type_id: nil, company_id: nil, billed_to: "employer", admin_user_id: nil, send_job_notifications: true, do_not_feature_jobs: false, company_type: nil, company_type_other: nil, company_restriction: nil, shortlist_count: nil>]
```

I would like to convert this result into an array that just looks like this

```
['Home Service', 'Aged and Disability Care']
```

These are the `name` of industries that i get from database.

This is what i tried

```
      industries.each do |industry|
        ind[] = industry['name']

      end
```

but I get an error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #

What am I doing wrong here?

This is what `j['Categories']` looks like

```
Disability Support Worker: Disability Support Worker
```

Comment: Quick question - if you're using `find_by_name` or `where(name: ...)` from `j['Categories']` and looking to select the industry's name... could you not just use the value of `j['Categories']`? (If not, @Jordan has the right answer) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built-in [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) method:

```
Industry.where(name: j['Categories']).pluck(:name)
```

This will be much more performant than `map`: The `map` solution will retrieve every column and instantiate an Industry object for each record, then call the `name` method on each object. `pluck` will retrieve only the given column and return an array of strings.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please take a moment to leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I'd appreciate the opportunity to improve it.